# jsf render components with js

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Let's say I have

```
<p:outputPanel/>
```

What I want to do is to specify rendered attr using js method not serverside.
This is for improving performance.
So I need something like :

```
<p:outputPanel rendered = "someJsFunction()"/>
```

What is the solution?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, is the serverside who defines which component will be rendered, in the client side it's just too late. css visible attribute might be a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rendered` propery is processed at server side and if it resolves to false, the `element` is not added into the html document. So `javascript` can't even find the element to **display** or **hide** because **it is not created**.

The only thing you can do is to remove the rendered property and change the display property of the element with javascript.

```
<div id="myDiv">My Content</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can have the same effect at page load cause `rendered` attribute is resolved at Server Side only , So using `jQuery` you can do it like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     document.getElementById("YourPanelIdHere").style.display = "none";
});
```

and it will be not displayed.

Comment: Not only that. If `rendered` evaluates to `false`, the component is not in the component tree view backed by JSF, thus it cannot be re-rendered unless it's inside another `UIContainer` like another `<p:panel>` and you update this parent container.